# Как сохранять ТОЛЬКО username в git

Tags: git, github

Каждый раз когда я делаю push/pull/clone git спрашивает мой юзернейм и пароль на гитхабе. 
`Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://username@github.com:`
Я нашел решение через `credential.helper` но оно сохраняет так же и пароль, мне же надо только хранение юзернейма. Есть какойто вариант?

Comment: А с какой целью Вам нужно сохранять только юзернейм? Не могу понять какая у Вас цель.

Comment: @V.March лень вводить каждый раз) Но пароль хранить не хочу, во первых как я понял он хранится не зашифрованный, во вторых оставлять взаимодействия с гитхабом совсем без защиты не хочется

Comment: Я пока не нашел такого способа. Хотя вводить длиннючий логин, а потом еще случайно ошибиться  при вводе пароля - очень таки раздражает. а ковыряться и что-то воротить сверх жлания небыло, так и  от риска что-то попутно сломать никто не застрахован. Можете попробовать с гитокрафтерами поговорить. Но учитывая кто гит выкупил - то боюсь что Ваш вопрос потеряется среди остальных.

Comment: Не надо использовать ни юзернейм ни пароль, надо использовать ssh-ключ ;)

Comment: @andreymal кстати тоже как вариант.

Comment: @andreymal Я ssh на гитлабе юзал - доволно удобно. Ну вот и появился повод добраться к гиту снова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это может быть не тот ответ, который вы ищете, но чем быстрее вы
перейдёте на аутентификацию через публичный *SSH*-ключ, тем быстрее
вы решите множество проблем для себя.  Если вы боитесь, что кто-то может
украсть ваш приватный ключ, для этого есть ключи с паролями (которые
кстати будут работать как раз так как вы хотите, спрашивать пароль, но
не юзернейм), а также двухфакторная авторизация через систему
одноразовых паролей.

У Гитхаба и Гитлаба есть прекрасные пошаговые гиды, которые помогут вам
настроить *SSH*+*2FA*:

- [*Connecting to GitHub with SSH*](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh)
- [*Configuring two-factor authentication*](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/configuring-two-factor-authentication)
- [*GitLab and SSH keys*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/)
- [*Two-Factor Authentication*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html)

Answer (score -1):

При использовании `credential.helper` пароли вашей учетной записи `git` будут сохранены в формате `global .gitconfig file` В нём хранятся данные, которые можно подправить.
Ещё можно установить логин таким образом(Инфо из [документации](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/setting-your-username-in-git)):
Но у меня это не сработало, всё равно запрашивал логин.

```
git config --global user.name "your username"
```

Можно использовать прям url к примеру:
`git config --global url."https://username:@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"`

Подробнее(Вариант вручную, если спецсимволы в username):
Вы можете сделать это в `.git/config` файле вашего локального хранилища. Этот файл содержит раздел под названием «remote» с записью под названием «url». Запись 'url' должна содержать ссылку на `https` репозитория

Заменив префикс хоста 'url' с вашим именем пользователя, больше gitне должны спрашивать ваше имя пользователя. Вот пример:

`url = https://username@repository-url.com`

Comment: А у кого это сработало?

Comment: @V.March Вы по git config user.name? Да вроде в самой документации github так написано. https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/setting-your-username-in-git А у кого сработало не могу сказать ))) Я заменил url )

Comment: Верно ли я понял, что сейчас Вы вводите только пароль, а логин уже приаттачен когда появляется поле авторизации?

Comment: @V.March Верно.

Comment: Это ж юзернейм для создания коммитов, а не для входа в гитхаб, не?

Comment: Нужно будет этот вариант поюзать. А то уже как год назад забил на этот вопрос - довольно неблагодарное дело рыться в том что с коробки работало.

Comment: @andreymal судя по вопросу то да, это со среды разработки push/pull/clone в   git аккаунт.